# How to create a circle pivot item in pivot control

Tags: pivot, geometry, pivotitem

I create a pivot control with 3 pivot item in my solution. And set SelectedIndex = 1 on load
On SelectionChanged event of pivot control, i want:
- when swipe to next pivot item: add a new pivot item and remove the first pivot item (index = 0)
- when swipe to pre pivot item: add a new pivot item to index = 0 and remove the last pivot item.

You can view this image:

[my idea, view this, please](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-cry4LmmYdUQ/T5bog38DvXI/AAAAAAAAATo/tDHcOA-Udbc/s640/Capture.jpg)

I trying, but have error

[my code, view this, please](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-l4_1PtSmWas/T5bpGeoc5QI/AAAAAAAAATw/zROIGF_z0zg/s781/Capture.jpg)

Have you any idea?
Thank very much.